# Unable to override Model in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, exception, mass-assignment

In the process of learning Laravel and following along with the video tutorials. During episode 11 @ 18 minutes 30 seconds in [here](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/11?autoplay=true).

1. The instructor creates a new file Model.php inside the app
   directory.
2. The new Model.php now extends Eloquent
3. Inside the new Model.php he adds `protected $guarded = [];`
4. He then extends the Post.php to the new Model.php

This allows him to define all the guarded fields in the new Model.php when doing a mass submission in his form. However when I fo this I still get a mass assignment exception.

If I change the Model.php to Models.php (notice the extra 's') then it works. I'm wondering why I can't have another file name Model.php inside the app directory to extend to?

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class Model extends Eloquent
{
    protected $guarded = [];
}
```

Comment: Copy paste and post  code of models you have there.

Comment: You are going to have to use the

 App\Model;

Instead of the 

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

Comment: Dam, @Serge you're right, I was an idiot. I was still extending Eloquent and not the model I wanted to use :/ thanks!

Comment: Ah cool... you can accept my answer and bring this question to a close... (and perk me some points... lol) Take care

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to have to use the App\Model; Instead of the use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;